# jQuery UI autocomplete multiple input controls with multiple JSON sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code working, from [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp):

```
var url = function(req, res){
    $.ajax({
        url: "getdata",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: req.term,
        },
        success: function(data){
            res($.map(data.students, function(item){
            return{
                label: item.cardId + "|" + item.firstName + " " + item.lastName,
                value: item.cardId
            }}))
        }
    });
};


$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: url
});
$("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
    source: url
});
```

And input elements:

```
<input path="students" id="autocomplete" style="z-index: 100; position: relative" title="type &quot;a&quot;" autofocus="autofocus" />
<input path="items" id="autocomplete2" style="z-index: 100; position: relative" title="type &quot;a&quot;" />
```

Both inputs have now the same dropdown list.
**Question:**
How to change url function to fit **students** and **items**? Or should just copy function for each type of input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `url` function, `this.element` will give you the element which fired autocomplete. You can use `this.element.attr("id")` or some other method to modify the JSONP url.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/YsxHJ/show/) and [**code here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/YsxHJ/)

Comment: It works! After hours of banging my head against the wall! Amazing Demo, thank for the tip!